# Issue transferring multiple files sequentially over java socket

Tags: java

I was hoping someone might be able to notice what I'm not noticing. I'm currently developing a system for a project at university, which involves creating an android app and java program which can transfer files between each other. In this specific use-case both programs are aware of the following details: The number of files which will be sent, the size of each file and which order they will be sent in.

This is the code within my android app:

```
try {
        Socket socket = new Socket(ip, port);
        ObjectOutputStream requestStream = new ObjectOutputStream(
                socket.getOutputStream());
        DataInputStream contentStream = new DataInputStream(
                socket.getInputStream());

        requestStream.writeObject(request);


        byte[] buf;
        File saveFile;
        for (File f : request.getFiles()) {
            saveFile = new File(saveLoc + f.getName());

            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(saveFile);

            int count = 0;

            buf = new byte[4096];

            long length = request.getFileSize(f.getName());
            while ((count = contentStream.read(buffer, 0,
                    (int) (Math.min(buffer.length, length-newFile.length())))) > 0) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, count);
                outputStream.flush();
            }

            outputStream.close();
        }
        contentStream.close();
        socket.close();
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

This is the code in my PC program:

```
try
    {
        DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        DataInputStream syncStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        byte[] buffer;

        for(File f : request.getFiles())
        {
            buffer = new byte[4096];
            FileInputStream fileInput = new FileInputStream(f);
            int count = 0;
            while((count = fileInput.read(buffer)) > -1)
            {
                output.write(buffer,0,count);
                output.flush();
            }
            fileInput.close();
        }
        output.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

}
```

My initial problem was that all of the bytes would be sent to the android app and saved to the first file in the transfer queue, resulting in one large file and multiple empty files. I then changed some of the stream code to use the methods involving offset/length because I read in another thread that that may solve my issue. My current issue however is that while the first file in the queue is written with the correct number of bytes, subsequent items are a small number of bytes off from what they should be. I'm pretty sure that I've made an error in the offset/length part, but I only have limited experience with socket programming.

In addition, this is the stacktrace on the pc program. It seems like the app closes the socket before the server has finished sending data.

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:118)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:159)
at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:107)
at java.io.FilterOutputStream.write(FilterOutputStream.java:97)
at com.sebastianmgibbs.QRBeam.pc.controller.ClientTransferController.transfer(ClientTransferController.java:66)
at com.sebastianmgibbs.QRBeam.pc.controller.ClientTransferController.run(ClientTransferController.java:33)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Comment: There's more code than this. Where is the code that reads from an `ObjectInputStream?` Also how does the end that *sends* the request know what the file length is going to be? NB don't `flush()` inside the loops.

Comment: Ah right yes sorry, In my tired state I left out some information which to me seemed somewhat irrelevant, however for continuity I should have included the code that receives the request object on the PC side. The app acquires the request object prior to this exchange, through another medium. You seem to have hit the nail on the head though with the flush() calls inside loops. It seems to work now. Thank you.